# Class exclude child class css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example I have the following situation:

```css
.divtest {
  display: flex;
}
.test{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="divtest">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Of course this do not work in my expected way. I want all elements to be flex displayed except the last one with class "test". Is it possible to exclude this "divtest" class for last element with "test" class? I am thinking about using **not()** but not sure how to do it.

Comment: what's the expected way? Could you provide an example of what should be the result with the given markup? I guess this is rather a X/Y problem

Comment: I want ALL elements to be displayed as FLEX except LAST ITEM.This paragraph with class "test" not to have the properties of .divtest. I want "test" paragraph not to be displayed on 1 row with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want "test" paragraph not to be displayed on 1 row with others

What you are trying to achieve cannot be managed by changing the `display` property of the child.

You just need to force it to be 100% wide and add wrapping to the parent.

```css
.divtest {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.test {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="divtest">
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="test">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks, it went well on project also.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-wrap

```
  .divtest {
  display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.test{
    display:block;
      width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: Nope. This is just a simple example. I just need to exclude all of these main div properties from sub-element.

Comment: I Updated my Answer can u please check it once

Comment: Sorry, no difference. I think the key is in using :not(). But not sure how

Answer (score -1):

Give everything display flex and override with your class:

```
.divtest, .divtest * {
  display: flex;
}

.divtest .test {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: Nope because <p class="test">This is another paragraph.</p> is still displaying on 1 row with all elements

Comment: Of course, paragraphs parent is still `flex`, you can't just flex a part of its children. You should look up what flex even does.